# How to check status of application for extension (Form 2350)

Tags: united-states, income-tax, foreign-income

I want to use the [Foreign Earned Income Exclusion](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion) when doing my U.S. taxes, but I have not yet been present in a foreign country for the required 330 days. Because of this, I used [Form 2350](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-2350), "Application for Extension of Time to File U.S. Income Tax Return". I mailed it almost two months ago. However, I have not yet received any notification telling me if my extension was approved or not.

Is there a way to check if my form was received and if it has been processed? If not, and assuming I don't receive a notice in time for the due date, do I have to file my taxes on the normal due date and without claiming the Income Exclusion?